# ICS Device lock during application run

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lockscreen

My Android device having ICS OS 4.0.4 does not lock the screen of the application when my app is running. This works well when I use the app on a device having OS < 4. Is there any change in implementation in ICS device? This leads to draining of the battery.

Please let me know if there are any config changes that needs to be set up to lock the screen.

Comment: check ICS properkey guard manager properties here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html

Comment: which device are you using??? It works on moto atrix 2